# Why does the literal value in a type long assignment still have an 'L' at the end in C++?

Tags: c++

Cant seem to find the answer to this, I'm sure it's simple, but just want to understand this so I can move on.

I'm looking at integer types, and am wondering why this:

```
long number = 645456645;
```

has the same effect as:

```
long number = 654456654L;
```

What is the point of using that letter 'L' at the end? Same with the 'U' for unsigned case.

Comment: Why have you used two different numbers, and then said that the effect is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking at Integer Types, and am wondering why this -
>
> ```
> long number = 645456645;
> ```
>
> has the same effect as -
>
> ```
> long number = 654456654L;
> ```

Strictly speaking, the two are not equivalent.

- In the former, your literal `645456645` has type `int` and is *converted* to `long` for the initialisation.
- In the latter, it's already a `long` so no conversion is performed.

In this trivial example there's obviously no functional difference, but on a platform where the range of `long` is not the same as the range of `int`, you may find that you *have* to use the `L` suffix to actually get the valid literal in the first place.

Comment: The first claim assumes that on the OP's flatform the number is an `int`. That's platform-dependent; it might already be a `long`.

Comment: Or `long long`. As clarification to the answer, integer literals choose their type based on a list of possible types and they take the first type that is able to represent the value. The suffixes restrict the list of possible types. E.g. an integer literal with no suffix is the first of the following types that can represent the value: `int`, `long`, or `long long`. A literal with the `L` suffix chooses from the list: `long`, or `long long`.

Comment: @bames53: Actually the literal `645456645` cannot have type `long long`, since `long` is guaranteed to be big enough to contain it. The minimum permissible value for `LONG_MAX` is `2147483647`. But for decimal literals in general, of course you're right, some of them do have type `long long`.

Answer (score 3):

The literal type specifier determines the *type* of the literal.

Naked integer literals always have the smallest possible `int`-type they fit, but with the specifier you can be explicit about the smalles type you wish to be considered:

```
12:    int             12U:    unsigned int
12L:   long int        12UL:   unsigned long int
12LL:  long long int   12ULL:  unsigned long long int
```

Imagine this:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T, T);
```

Now `foo(12, 12L)` fails because it is ambiguous, but `foo(12U, 12U)` works (and `T` is deduced as `unsigned int`). So literal type specifiers can be very important when you need to control the actual type of a literal expression.

Comment: "Naked integer literals always have the smallest possible type they fit", but at least `int`, you can't have an integer literal that has type `short`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: yes, good point, I added that. I guess the base type for naked literals is always the same as the base type used in variadic function arguments, if that helps (`int` and `double`).

Answer (score 2):

It's to specify the type of the integer literal. `L` makes it a `long` and `U` makes it unsigned.

The use of it is cases like this:

```
long long number = 123456789123456;
long long number = 123456789123456LL;
```

Some compilers will complain about the first one since `123456789123456` doesn't fit in the default `int`.

The other case where it is used is to disambiguate between overloaded functions.

---

**EDIT: (see comments)**

**main.cpp**

```
int main(){

    long long number = 123456789123456;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it gives:

```
alex-desktop:~/Desktop/vm_shared> g++ main.cpp
main.cpp:3: warning: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type
alex-desktop:~/Desktop/vm_shared>
```

gcc version: 4.4.3

Comment: Show me a platform where `123456789123456L` is valid.

Comment: Sorry, bad example, since `long` is the same as `int` on Windows. EDIT: Though `long` is 64-bits on Linux.

Comment: If `123456789123456LL` is valid for a compiler then it shouldn't complain about `123456789123456` because when choosing the type integer constants, the implementation must chose a type in which the constant fits.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: g++ emits a warning without the `LL`. `main.cpp:6: warning: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type`. VS2010 doesn't complain though.

Comment: @Mysticial: Are you sure you are compiling the code that is initializing a `long long` with the constant?

Comment: @Mysticial: Are you sure you are using C++11 (C++0x) mode (it's not the default in my version of g++)? `long long` is not legal in C++03 (C++98). I only get this warning when using `-std=c++98` mode with `long long` which is, of course, non-standard.

Comment: Actually, no I'm not sure. This is the gcc version that I happen to have on my VM installation. I've encountered this many times before so hence why I always have to use `LL`. But you're right in that it's probably non-standard behavior.

Comment: This issue with your posted code is that in the rules for choosing the type of an integer constant only the types `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int` and `unsigned long int` are considered in C++03 as `long long int` and `long long unsigned int` are not C++03 types. This means there is no value type in which the constant actually fits (on this implementation, there's no problem on amd64). If you use `-pedantic` you should also get the warning: `ISO C++ 1998 does not support ‘long long’ [-Wlong-long]`. Using the `LL` suffix should also give: `warning: use of C++0x long long integer constant`.

Comment: Ah, I figured as such. I'm aware that `long long` didn't exist until `C++11`. But since the work-around is so simple, (append `LL`) I never tried to understand the semantics on why it would warn in the first place. That's good to know.

Comment: Yes, there should never be a warning about truncation that could be fixed merely by the addition of an `L` or `LL` suffix because if there is a type in which the constant fits, the implementation must use it even when the suffix isn't used. Also, just for clarification, decimal literals only consider the signed types, only hexadecimal and octal constants can have unsigned type if a suffix isn't specified.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a literal such as this will be interpreted as an integer, and occasionally you want to specify a literal that is too big for an integer (> INT_MAX), in these cases you use such suffix, `L` and `LL` (`U` etc.), which tells the compiler to treat the literal as a `long` (and `long long`)